# exec-PHP shows output at bottom of page

Tags: plugins, php

I'm using the latest Wordpress release with the default theme.

I have a function similar to this which is included and called from within a page (using exec-PHP).

```
<?php function myFunc($value) {
        while () // some condition {
             echo $value;
        }
 ?>
 <?php myFunc('val'); ?>
```

the output of the `echo` function is appearing at the bottom of the page instead of appearing within the correct page content section.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcode and return the content instead of echoing it out so in your functions.php file add:

```
function myFunc($atts,$content = null) {
    while (ture) {
       return $content;
    }
    return '';
}

add_shortcode('myfunc','myFunc');
```

and in your page's content instead of using exec-PHP just call your new shortcode:

```
[myfunc]val[/myfunc]
```